# How can I select elements that contain only children with a given class?

Tags: jquery, css

CSS or jQuery. Is there a selector to set a children class constraint like this?

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Not a duplicate as such.

Comment: Not a duplicate since I didn't ask for a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector

```
$('.elements:has(.children)')
```

This is a jQuery only selector, and it's not available in CSS.

To select elements that **only** contains elements with a certain class

```
$('.elements').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('*').length == $(this).find('.children').length;
})
```

Comment: Note that there currently **isn't a way to select parents based on children with with CSS**. They're thinking about incorporating a `:has()` pseudoselector in the future though (just to fully answer OP's question).

Comment: @CaseyFalk - That is correct, I'll add that as well

Comment: Will that select divs that **only** contain elements of that class or any parent element that contains an element with that class? I think the former is required (based on the OP's title?).

Comment: @Paulie_D - It will select elements that contain that class, the question is a bit unclear, but I'll add something.

Comment: Cool...I think you'd need some sort of length function to achieve the **only** bit..right? My JS/JQ skills are minimal.

Comment: Thanks guys, the filter hack seems the best option I get. Yes, the "only" part is required, I don't think the question is unclear.

Comment: @user3280015 - you're welcome, and the question wasn't really unclear, I just didn't get it at first.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

parent-element > child-element.class-your-are-after {

//do something here

}

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that OP wants to select the *parent* in the question, @lili2311.

Comment: No that will select the child elements which is not what the OP is after and in any case, is not a filter.

Comment: yep misread the question! thanks